# How to link image in react.js using source

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, zurb-foundation

I am working on a react.js website and I want to link a image (logo) to the website. See folder structure

[image]

My image code for the footer logo is

```
<img className="img-responsive" src="public/assets/image/img/footer-logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
```

But the image is not visible on the website when I run it. Any solutions??

Answer (score 8):

If you are using webpack and assuming you are in one of the components as displayed in the image then do:

```
import logo from '../../public/assets/image/img/foorter-logo.jpg';
<img className="img-responsive" src={logo} alt="logo"/>
```

If you want to stick to what you have then you can do:

```
<img className="img-responsive" src="../../public/assets/image/img/footer-logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You image src url need to be relative to the file you are using it in. So You need to use it like `../../public/assets/image/img/footer-logo.jpg`.

Also in react you need to enclose your source within curly brackets

```
<img className="img-responsive" src={"../../public/assets/image/img/footer-logo.jpg"} alt="logo"/>
```

Also if you are using webpack you need to use require with the image src url like

```
<img className="img-responsive" src={require("../../public/assets/image/img/footer-logo.jpg")} alt="logo"/>
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar bug working on a simple Gatsby test. 
My path was like: 
[image: Image of problem]

To resolve as @Kafo stated:

1. Give your image a named import
2. Wrap that in curly braces as the value of src

My result: 
[image: Result]